# How to generate a pairlist with no defaults without using alist?

Tags: r, metaprogramming, s-expression

I'm experimenting with simple manipulation of R code and trying to generate an object equivalent to

```r
substitute(function(x) x)
```

I am aware I can do something around these lines

```r
as.call(list(as.symbol("function"), as.pairlist(alist(x=)), as.symbol("x")))
```

but I am looking for a way to achieve `as.pairlist(alist(x=))` without resorting `alist` or, if that's not possible, allowing me to generate equivalent expression without hard-coding the thing or parsing strings.

I was tinkering with things like `as.call(list(as.symbol("="), as.symbol("x")))`, but that's seems to be a dead end for now.

Comment: What do you mean by "generate [an] equivalent expression without hard-coding the thing or parsing strings"? It's not really clear what level of generality you are looking for. Do you want to be able to generate an arbitrary named (tagged) pairlist of formals given some names and (optionally) values?

Comment: @MikaelJagan Basically, what you've already guessed ‒ looking for a programmatic way to create `alist`, if getting a `pairlist` directly is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A programmatic alternative to `as.pairlist(alist(...))` is to initialize a pairlist of positive length then assign names (well, "tags") and values:

```r
zzz <- vector("pairlist", 1L)
names(zzz) <- "x"
zzz[[1L]] <- substitute()

identical(zzz, as.pairlist(alist(x = )))
## [1] TRUE
```

More generally:

```r
pl <- function(n, tags, values) {
    r <- vector("pairlist", n)
    if (n >= 1L) {
        names(r) <- tags
        for (i in seq_len(n)) {
            v <- values[[i]]
            if (missing(v) || !is.null(v))
                r[[i]] <- values[[i]]
        }
    }
    r
}

identical(pl(3L, c("x", "y", "z"), list(substitute(), 0, NULL)),
          as.pairlist(alist(x = , y = 0, z = NULL)))
## [1] TRUE
```

We condition on `n >= 1L` because a zero-length pairlist is `NULL` and assigning names or values to `NULL` is an error.

We condition on `missing(v) || !is.null(v)` because we don't want to assign `NULL` to `r[[i]]` (which would decrease the length of `r` by 1) and we don't want to call `is.null` with no argument:

```r
v <- substitute()
missing(v)
## [1] TRUE
is.null(v)
## Error: argument "v" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I'm looking for. Is there any reference for this usage of `substitute`?

Comment: It isn't a documented usage, partly on purpose on the part of R-core, but you'll likely find discussion on one of the mailing lists. (Every few years someone asks about the "missing" symbol.) And of course you can always look at the source code of `substitute`, written in C.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much scope for avoiding `alist`, other than stealing the pairlist from an anonymous function definition using `formals`:

```r
as.function(c(formals(\(x){}), quote(x)))
#> function (x) 
#> x
```

Or stealing from a built-in function:

```r
as.function(c(formals(mean)[1], quote(x)))
#> function (x) 
#> x
```